# How to connect to heroku pg from local machine?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

[This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup) document says to set DATABASE_URL=postgres://$(whoami) this to maintain parity between local and pro dbs. But what should I replace "whoami" with?

I have installed PostGreSql on my machine. How to I perform CRUD operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `whoami` will return `username of the current user` when invoked. As the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup) said, you just need to type the below in command prompt (no need to replace `whoami`), depends on your OS:

1. Linux / Mac:

   ```
   export DATABASE_URL=postgres://$(whoami)
   ```
2. Windows:

   ```
   set DATABASE_URL=postgres://$(whoami)
   ```

After set up Postgres, you can use `psql` client to access the database. As you asked in comment regarding how to run `.sql` file, here's the steps:

1. In command prompt, type `"psql"`. You are now connected to your database.
2. Inside `psql`, type `"\i your_sql_file.sql"`. This execute the `your_sql_file.sql` file.

Comment: Thanks for help. How do I run .sql file from my local machine?

Comment: What machine are you using? From the documentation, follow `Set up postgres on ...` , depends on your OS: Linux / Mac / Windows. Then use `psql` to run the sql file.

Comment: @NikeshDevaki I edited my answer to show how to run `.sql` file.